# Prime Faces equivalent for django?

Tags: django, primefaces

I love Prime Faces for Java Server Faces. I am doing a project in Django and would like to do something similar. Is there an equivalent for Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for ajax you can use http://www.dajaxproject.com/

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is extjs with [django-extjs](https://github.com/revolunet/django-extjs).